# How to include a hyperlink when converting from Excel to Wiki-tables?

Tags: microsoft-excel, hyperlink, wiki

I use Excel to create tables that include a column of hyperlinked cells. Now I want to convert this data into Wiki-table format.  If I use tab2wiki (https://magnustools.toolforge.org/tab2wiki.php), I lose the hyperlink. What tool is available that carries over the hyperlink in the conversion?

Answer (score 1):

If you know what a table looks like in wiki code, you can create almost the entire table source code in Excel itself. The beginning and closing of a table you will add in the wiki source code. For example creating hyperlinks would be something like A1 = `[[`, B1 = *target article name*, C1 = `]]`, D1 = =`A1&B1&C1`.

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, the best course of action would be to extend the `tab2wiki` tool with link-handling support (source code [here](https://bitbucket.org/magnusmanske/magnustools/src/master/)), especially given the explosion of generic TLDs in the last few years. Nothing beats writing purpose-built code to handle the problem, which is more complex than this limited solution (detailed below) can handle.

That being said, I was able to hack together something with regex and perl that *might* do what you need, depending on your conditions, at least if you have access to Linux or else can adapt this approach to a different environment. I believe [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), available on Windows, supports regex in its find-replace tool, and you might be able to adapt this approach to use that interface with the below regex (i.e., paste the output of `tab2wiki` into notepad++ and then use the regex in its find-replace).

First, the input, which is provided to `tab2wiki`:

```
lol wut noway   asdf
1   no way https://www.google.com so cool https://test.net  qwer    zxcv
2       http://kagi.org sd
3   fd  d   https://netflix.org
4   fdasf   f   http://www.apple.org
```

Which, when pasted into `tab2wiki` produces the following text:

```
{| border="1" class="sortable"
!lol!!wut!!noway!!asdf
|-
|1||no way https://www.google.com so cool https://test.net||qwer||zxcv
|-
|2||||http://kagi.org||sd
|-
|3||fd||d||https://netflix.org
|-
|4||fdasf||f||http://www.apple.org
|}
```

This example includes cells with multiple links, as well as ending cells that have links at the very end, as well as empty cells.

Saving this file somewhere, a la `/tmp/testwikifile`, and then performing the following command with `perl`'s regex engine, goes around and sticks the `[` and `]` around each of the links:

`cat /tmp/testtable3 | perl -p -e 's/(http.*?)\.(com|org|net)/\[\1.\2\]/gm'`

The output:

```
{| border="1" class="sortable"
!lol!!wut!!noway!!asdf
|-
|1||no way [https://www.google.com] so cool [https://test.net]||qwer||zxcv
|-
|2||||[http://kagi.org]||sd
|-
|3||fd||d||[https://netflix.org]
|-
|4||fdasf||f||[http://www.apple.org]
|}
```

---

Limitations:

1. The links have to start with `http` at least
2. The list of top-level domains (TLDs) for the links needs to be known

Details of regex:

This regex, `'s/(http.*?)\.(com|org|net)/\[\1.\2\]/g'`, can be broken down as follows:

1. Perform a substitution of an input string with a new string a la `s/start/replacement/`, and do it globally `g` (find all matches).
2. Search for `http` plus anything else `.*` and do it **lazily** `?`. Then find a period `\.`, then find one of `com`, `org`, or `net` via `(com|org|net)`. This establishes two capture groups which we can then use in our substitution.
3. The substitution is `\[\1.\2\]`, with `\1` being everything from `http` to the period, and `\2` being one of `com`, `org`, or `net`. Hence, "put a period `.` between these two matches to re-make the link, and pad the link with opening `[` and closing `]` brackets."

Comment: This makes sense.  I  usually use Windows and Notepad++, but I also have a Linux machine I am learning on. I always know the top-level domain (FamilySearch).,  but the ending is never with the .org but rather after it. For example, https://www.familysearch.org/ark:/61903/1:1:F73Y-17X.  Hmm, Maybe I can go 3 characters after the -  How do I do that?